# base url for code igniter site not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, base-url

New to CodeIgniter and getting my feet wet.

Older (5yr old?) CI website. Moved it to new webhosting at A2 and got things set up.

Home page appears, however, the base URL doesn't seem to be working for the site. I have not made DNS changes yet, so using IP and sub-folder on the FTP.

application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/blah.com/';
```

also tried

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/blah.com/';
```

but when site loads, css is missing as it's trying to load

```
<link href="/assets/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="/assets/css/public.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

etc.

even though the URL in the browser shows

http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/blah.com/

the assets and stuff are trying to be loaded at

http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/

Here is my htaccess file.

```
# Deny access to the htaccess file
<FILES .htaccess>
order allow,deny 
deny from all
</FILES>

# Prevent these script from executing anything
Options -ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .pl .py .jsp .shtml .sh .asp .cgi

# Make it so sessions are available on all sub-domains
#php_value session.cookie_domain .prelicensetraining.com

# Prevent directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# Code Igniter Clean URL Rewrites
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Extra notes: Was initially have trouble with a 500 internal server error on new webhosting at A2. Opened ticket and received the following from support. Now it's connecting to db, but as I mentioned above, the base URL setting is not working properly.

"This was due to the software using an older mysql extension, which is no longer supported under PHP 7+. We installed cPanel's MultiPHP system and set blah.com to use PHP 5.6, then updated the application/config/database.php file to use 'localhost' as the database host and we now get a login page at http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/blah.com/ ."

Comment: The HTML code you posted, how is `base_url` supposed to be used there?

Comment: It's not. I was just trying to show a reference of assets loading at wrong base URL. Thanks. For some reason, base URL setting in config.php ignores /blah.com/ part of the URL. No idea why this happening.

Comment: I think you don't understand how the `base_url` is used in CodeIgniter

Comment: Perhaps not. I'm trying to understand. Site was working fine at old webhost. Moved to new one, and I updated that setting in application/config/config.php because it showed old URL before, and now it's not loading assets. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turned out to be an issue with outdated Code Igniter framework. After a long weekend, overhauled the code to bring up to date and it works now with the baseURL setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the `base_url` in your HTML code, you are currently "manually" loading the assets:

```
<link href="/assets/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

The `/` at the start tells the browser to load the assets from the root folder.

You can use the `base_url()` function to generate links, this function is available if you load the URL helper, you can use it like this:

```
base_url('assets/css/global.css');
```

This will return:

> http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/blah.com/assets/css/global.css

So use it like this:

```
<link href="<?=base_url('assets/css/global.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

`<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`

You can load the URL helper with this code:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Also check it in the **inspect element** OR right click on your site and click on **View page Source**  to see the correct path of the file and change accordingly.